# What is the law behind this sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

Can you figure out the rule that produces this sequence?

> 10, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 21, 21, 23, 207, 207, 211, 213, 213, 215

What is the next term?

Here's a hint:

> Even if it seems otherwise, the sequence does not contain repeated numbers.

Comment: Re the hint, it does. 4 times. Surely the sequence is what you gave, not what it was generated from.

Comment: @bg6471: It contains repeated digit sequences, but not repeated numbers. A digit sequence is not a number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your sequence is

> the prime numbers written base n
>  for n = 2, 3, 4, ... and you reserve two digits as base n > 10

for example

> 2 =  10  base 2
>   3 =  10  base 3
>   5 =  11  base 4
>   7 =  12  base 5
>  11 =  15  base 6
>  13 =  16  base 7
>  17 =  21  base 8
>  19 =  21  base 9
>  23 =  23  base 10
>  29 = 207  base 11 (reserving two digits as using base 10 for two digit  numbers)
>  ...
>  and so on until

the next term in the sequence after 215 is

> 302 as it is 53 written in base 17 using this notation

Comment: You got everything right *except* the final number. You gave a wrong base, and even if the base were right, the value would not be valid in the base you gave.

Comment: Thanks celtschk for this and yes you are right  - I have corrected the final term!

Comment: Now everything is correct. Well done!